# is List<T>(List<T>) constructor thread safe?

Tags: c#

When I have this code:

```
public static List<Module> ExtensionList
{
    get
    {
        return new List<Module>(Extensions);
    }
}
```

is it thread safe? eg. does it issue the lock on `Extensions` while it copies the list? or should I explicitly do that:

```
public static List<Module> ExtensionList
{
    get
    {
        lock (Extensions)
        {
            return new List<Module>(Extensions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. According to MSDN, all non-static members in `List<T>` are not guarraned to be thread safe: "Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @pwas why is it a bad practice? can you elaborate? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) states clearly that no method of `List<T>` is thread-safe:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read.

The constructor *itself* is always thread-safe: you can't call it from another instance yet.

If you supply your `List<T>` constructor with another `List<T>`, like you do in your code, it isn't safe since the incoming `List<T>` might change while being processed by the constructor (then the above rule applies).

Comment: I can approve of that. I just reflected the .NET code and there is no lock statement, monitor or something else related.

Comment: But that's boiler-plate text and it hardly matters here. It's very hard (impossible?) to use a constructor multi-threaded. The question is really about the parameter.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: That is in the answer right? I state clearly that if a List<T> is used as incoming parameter it isn't safe. If the parameterless constructor is called, it IS safe.

Comment: Only slightly. Point is that the quoted text is irrelevant.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it is: when you execute that code and different thread modifies the List which was being copied within that constructor, it would probably throw some exception

Comment: @Petr: indeed, but that's about the thread-safety of the List, not that of the ctor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: But I state that if you supply a `List<T>` to the constructor it isn't thread safe. It's about two `List<T>`s!

Comment: And it still is about the thread-safety of the first (incoming) list only. How would you ever call a constructor for 1 instance from 2 threads?

Comment: You are right about that. I think we just read the question differently. The code as a whole isn't thread safe. The constructor of course is.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Updated the answer further to make specific that the constructor on itself is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you set the construcutor in a lock statement the useage of the list would not be threadsafe.

Use a thread-safe collection like a BlockingCollection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No. Thread-safe collection simplify syntax - we don't need to use `lock` or any method to lock. But properly used `lock` can provide thread-safety for any operation.

Comment: Axdorph is right in that the second sample with `lock()` does not guarantee thread-safety by itself. Correctness depends on other code accessing Extensions.

Comment: @Ok - right, outside class must also properly use a lock.